# How to read xml from web service in symbian application

Tags: java, xml, web-services, java-me, symbian

i have web service which returns data in xml format... i have searched google and everybody is giving solution in which they are reading from xml file.. i mobile please provide some specific solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use KXML with Java-Me application and parse the XML data. See this [link](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/parsingxml/). Here clearly described how to use and how to parsing the XML data. For more info see this [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wi-parsexml/) also.